# Зафиксировать первую строку в listView

Tags: java, android, listview

Имеется listview который выводит n строк, нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке этого списка, первая его строка всегда была на виду, т.е. не скролилась. Как это реализовать?

Comment: заголовок устроит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать просто вьюху отдельно от листвью и привязать ее к верху.

Comment: да, вы правы, так проще всего)